# Multiple dropdowns with dependancy

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to display 4 dropdowns, the items in each dropdown, depends on selected item in previous dropdown.

I want to implement everything in javascript, meaning the servlet should access DB (everything is stored in one reference  table, where a column "represents" a dropwdown ) only once and fetch all the relevant data.

The maximum number of possible combinations is about 9k.

How can I achieve that?
I guess the main problem is the data structure that should be used for this.
Maybe use of nested Maps?

Comment: Its a bad idea. Sending the entire database to the user on each request is massive overhead. Plus it means once the user has accessed your page once, they have your whole database.

Comment: I must avoid trips to server and back to client.

Comment: If you just want to avoid the page refreshing you can use AJAX.

Comment: I understand, but still need a client side solution